# refresh datepicker after onselect

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker for my application.

I want to highlight the dates selected by the user.
User will select a date and that date is added to the database as holiday and the the date should become highlighted. I am already having some dates in database which will be highlighted before using beforeShowDay event and also i have disabled the weekends.

everything is working fine except that i am unable to highlight that date after adding it to database. it is getting highlighted only when i am reloading the calendar.

I searched on internet but didn't got any clear idea, so many places it is suggested to use multidatepicker but the point is at a time I am selecting only one date adding it to database then selecting other.

please suggest me where i am going wrong.
My code is--

```
var dates = [ <? php echo $holidays; ?> ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#calendardisplay").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        onSelect: dateSelected
    });

    function dateSelected(dateText, inst) {
        $.post('/postChannelHoliday.php', {
            'date': dateText
        }, function (data) {
            alert('Successfully Added');
        });
    }
}

function holiday(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString().substr(0, 16) == date.toString().substr(0, 16)) {
            return [true, 'ui-state-highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

function highlightDays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return holiday(date);
    } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}
});
```

i am including a php file to get the dates stored in the database to highlight them in calendar

Comment: Your indentation is truly horrible.

Comment: `var dates = [ <? php echo $holidays; ?> ];` looks really bad. Have you heard about `json_encode()`? You can simply use `var dates = <?php echo json_encode($holidayArray); ?> ;` and it will always be valid JavaScript - no matter what the array contains.

Comment: @ThiefMaster -but can you tell me how to highlight those dates which are being added by user in database without refreshing or is it necessary to refresh in my code

Comment: @ThiefMaster -sorry for the indentation, and thanks for suggesting the use of json_encode().

Comment: For future reference, I'd suggest putting your code on jsfiddle.net and linking to it here so that we can work on your code and help you even quicker!

Comment: @arboc7, code is expected to be in the question - make sure when you suggest putting code somewhere else to note that it should be copy of the code in the question, not the only place where code is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `alert` you need to update list of your holidays (look like `dates` global object) and than force update of the datepicker by calling [refresh](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-refresh) on it.